# Chroot - помойка в структуре директорий тюрьмы

Tags: linux, chroot

Делаю chroot-окружение, получаю в `/home/jail/` (она же ChrootDirectory, она же хомяк) следующую структуру:

```
bin
dev
lib64
etc
и др. системные директории
www - директория с сайтами chroot-пользователя
```

т.е. получается помойка. Хотелось бы привести структуру `/home/jail/` (она же ChrootDirectory, она же хомяк) к следующему виду:

```
.bin
    |__ bin
    |__ dev
    |__ lib64
    |__ etc
    |__ и др. системные директории
www - директория с сайтами chroot-пользователя
```

Можно ли как-то этого добиться - может изменением PATH, может поднятием из chroot на один уровень выше, может еще как-то?

Comment: Сделать `.bin` chroot'ом, а в каталог `.bin/www` подключить внешний каталог `www` через какой-нибудь `mount --bind`?

Comment: `www` должен находиться на одном уровне с `.bin`, а уже внутри `.bin` должны лежать все системные директории. Т.е. чтобы когда chroot-пользователь входил в свое окружение через SSH и SFTP, видел `.bin` и `www`

Comment: Это невозможно, потому что сломает совместимость с большинством линуксовых программ, которые рассчитаны на использование "помойных" путей

Comment: а если chroot используется только для sftp, то ему не нужна вся эта мишура...

Comment: >> которые рассчитаны на использование "помойных" путей
-->
)) Ок, значит как-то иначе буду решать.


>> а если chroot используется только для sftp, то ему не нужна вся эта мишура
-->
Не только SFTP, но и SSH